# Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, bool give in , Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, web, mysqli

I have a problem. I did not understand exactly what the problem is. I tried more than one way but I could not find the solution. I think this is the right place. I hope someone will help me.

```
if(isset($login)){
if(empty($adminMail) || empty($adminPass)){
echo "<div class='alert alert-danger'>"."Please enter your username and password "."</div>";
}
else{

$query="SELECT * FROM admin WEHRE email=$adminMail AND password=$adminPass";
$result= mysqli_query($conn,$query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
      echo $row['email'];
}        
}
```

Comment: You should use a prepared statement instead. Then your error would magically disappear.

Comment: Also, ***HASH YOUR PASSWORDS***, storing them in plaintext is not secure at all!

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60496/1839439) and should use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](https://php.net/manual/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](https://php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input! Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/). [Escaping is not enough!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5741187)

Comment: **Never store passwords in clear text or using MD5/SHA1!** Only store password hashes created using PHP's [`password_hash()`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php), which you can then verify using [`password_verify()`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php). Take a look at this post: [How to use password_hash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30279321/1839439) and learn more about [bcrypt & password hashing in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6337021/1839439)

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7537500/285587) for the proper syntax